# why scroll down navigation bar is not changing the color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

here is my [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-shtern-e7gur)

in the browser i want to scroll down the page the the navbar will say what color i am showing.

```
 <div style={{height: "800px"}}>
        <h2 style={{backgroundColor: `${nav}`,
            position: "fixed",

            width: "100%"
          }}
        >
          NaveBar {nav ? "red" : "blue"}!
        </h2>
      </div>
```

it's somewhat not changing the name of the title and color also.i just dun know where is the problem.

can somebody help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized the state with a string  `useState("red");`
and then you update the state to an object with `setNav({ back });`

To solve this just change it to `setNav(back)`

---

By the way - listening to scroll-events can be laggy, so you might want to "throttle" the event.

import throttle from lodash or just copy paste this function:
https://gist.github.com/abhinavnigam2207/a147abe0213d60467abacd33db7c6d2e

Then you use it by wrapping your function into it, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      throttle(() => {
        const back = window.scrollY < 70 ? "red" : "blue";
        setNav(back);
      }, 100)
    );
  });
```

Comment: without throttle it's working .... at least changing the color which was my main concern. and with throttle it is working also fine.... i would like to know more about the throttle but the solution you gave is just very clever.... seems like there is no limit of understanding this react.... it´s frustrating that why i am doing such tiny mistakes... thanx any way

Comment: Add `console.log(nav)` just before the `return (<div...)`. Now look at how much console-logs you produce. Try adding throttle and see the difference :)